# Send audio to two video muxes

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux

I'm developing an embedded app for a custom hardware device (using an NXP i.MX 8M+ running Linux, for those who are interested).  The hardware is being developed by others on the project.

In my app, I need to receive video from its two MIPI camera devices and one PDM microphone.  I'm encoding the video to H.264 (using a vendor-supplied hardware encoder plugin, `vpuenc_h264`) and passing each stream to `mpegtsmux`, and then saving to MP4 files (one for each camera's feed).

A subset of the GST pipeline this app uses (content not needed to illustrate the problem omitted) is:

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0
! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=GRAY8
! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux1
! filesink
v4l2src device=/dev/video1
! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=GRAY8
! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux2
! filesink
```

This part works great.

When I want to mux the audio in to the stream to be included with the video in the files, I can add it to one of the muxes this way:

```
alsasrc device=\"hw:0,0\"
! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=22050, channels=1
! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac name=audio_aac
! mux1.
```

This works great.  But if I try to take the AAC-encoded audio and split it with a tee so it goes to both muxes, it doesn't work:

```
alsasrc device=\"hw:0,0\"
! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=22050, channels=1
! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac name=audio_aac
! tee name=taudio
  taudio. ! mux1.
  taudio. ! mux2.
```

The above fails.  If I turn on GST debugging, I see these messages:

```
ERROR GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:773:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link taudio to mux1
ERROR GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:773:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link taudio to mux2
```

Just in case it helps, here's what I see for mux1 (identical traces for mux2) with the GST debug level turned up a bit higher:

```
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1948:gst_element_link_pads_full: linked pad audio_aac:src to pad taudio:sink
INFO      GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:4377:gst_bin_get_by_name: [pipeline0]: looking up child element taudio
INFO      GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:4377:gst_bin_get_by_name: [pipeline0]: looking up child element mux1
INFO       GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:683:gst_parse_perform_link: linking pad  taudio of GstTee named taudio to pad  mux1 of GstMpegTsMux named mux1 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
INFO   GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1816:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element taudio:(any) to element mux1:(any)
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1925:gst_element_link_pads_full: looping through allowed src and dest pads
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1928:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying src pad taudio:sink
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1991:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying dest pad mux1:src
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1991:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying dest pad mux1:sink_65
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:2043:gst_element_link_pads_full: we might have request pads on both sides, checking...
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:2097:gst_element_link_pads_full: no link possible from taudio to mux1
INFO            default gstutils.c:2206:gst_element_link_pads_filtered: Could not link pads: taudio:(null) - mux1:(null)
ERROR      GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:773:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link taudio to mux1
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1948:gst_element_link_pads_full: linked pad audio_aac:src to pad taudio:sink
INFO      GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:4377:gst_bin_get_by_name: [pipeline0]: looking up child element taudio
INFO      GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:4377:gst_bin_get_by_name: [pipeline0]: looking up child element mux1
INFO       GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:683:gst_parse_perform_link: linking pad  taudio of GstTee named taudio to pad  mux1 of GstMpegTsMux named mux1 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
INFO   GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1816:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element taudio:(any) to element mux1:(any)
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1925:gst_element_link_pads_full: looping through allowed src and dest pads
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1928:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying src pad taudio:sink
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1991:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying dest pad mux1:src
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1991:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying dest pad mux1:sink_65
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:2043:gst_element_link_pads_full: we might have request pads on both sides, checking...
DEBUG  GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:2097:gst_element_link_pads_full: no link possible from taudio to mux1
INFO            default gstutils.c:2206:gst_element_link_pads_filtered: Could not link pads: taudio:(null) - mux1:(null)
ERROR      GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:773:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link taudio to mux1
```

If, however, I tee the audio before the AAC encoding, the result is good:

```
alsasrc device=\"hw:0,0\"
! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=22050, channels=1
! queue
! tee name=taudio
  taudio. ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac name=audio_aac1 ! mux1.
  taudio. ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac name=audio_aac2 ! mux2.
```

The above works great.

Any idea why I can tee raw audio but not AAC-encoded audio?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Comment: I wonder if this is audio as part of a software product, and thus might be an edge-case that I would personally allow. I think it is too involved for _Super User_, where audio configuration questions would normally go. Could you clarify David?

Comment: I've updated the description with some prologue explaining that, yes, this GStreamer pipeline is being used in an embedded Linux application.  It is definitely a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix on another forum ( https://discourse.gstreamer.org/t/cant-tee-aac-encoded-audio-but-can-tee-raw-audio/847/3 ).  It appears that inserting a queue between the tee and the mux makes it all work:

```
alsasrc device=\"hw:0,0\"
! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=22050, channels=1
! audioconvert ! avenc_aac
! tee name=taudio
  taudio. ! queue ! mux1.
  taudio. ! queue ! mux2.
```

I still don't know why this should be necessary, but at least with this approach I don't need to run the AAC encoder twice for identical data.